# Styled-jsx React native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, styled-components

I am trying to implement `styled-jsx` in React native project. I am following this tutorial : https://github.com/zeit/styled-jsx

I have added this code :

**.babelrc :**

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"
    ]
}
```

**Screen :**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import _JSXStyle from 'styled-jsx/style'
export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="jsx-123">
                <p className="jsx-123">only this paragraph will get the style :)</p>
                <_JSXStyle id="123">{`p.jsx-123 {color: red;}`}</_JSXStyle>
            </div>
        )
    };
}
```

**But I am getting following error :**

[image]

**============ UPDATE ============**

I have removed one import _JSXStyle from 'styled-jsx/style'.

**styled-jsx/babel :**

```
module.exports = require('./dist/babel'),
    {
        "plugins": [
            ["styled-jsx/babel", { "optimizeForSpeed": false }]
        ]
    }
```

**Now i am getting this error :**

[image]

Please advice if you have tried this. May be I am missing any files then please let me know.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Your mistake**
You tried the example of **how it works** part. Where the library developer indicated that how it looks after compile, So, please follow the doc. For your better understanding, I'm giving it here.

Firstly, install the package:

```sh
npm install --save styled-jsx
```

Next, add `styled-jsx/babel` to `plugins` in your babel configuration:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "styled-jsx/babel"
  ]
}
```

Now add `<style jsx>` to your code and fill it with CSS:

```
export default () => (
  <div>
    <p>only this paragraph will get the style :)</p>

    { /* you can include <Component />s here that include
         other <p>s that don't get unexpected styles! */ }

    <style jsx>{`
      p {
        color: red;
      }
    `}</style>
  </div>
)
```

**Note:** According to the doc it should work. https://github.com/zeit/styled-jsx#getting-started

Comment: Can you please tell me that where i will find this styled-jsx/babel ?currently i have added this code in .babelrc

Comment: still i am getting that document error :( . can you please explain a bit mre that where which file and which code will be. as i am trying this first time

Comment: `npm install --save styled-jsx` After install you will get it on node_modules

Comment: In that i have this code : module.exports = require('./dist/babel')
should i add this code after this or in any array

Comment: No. It should work. If not please re-run your project.

Comment: No i am asking that file already have some code so now it will look like module.exports = require('./dist/babel'),
    {
        "plugins": [
            "styled-jsx/babel"
        ]
    }
correct??

Comment: Please explain a bit more for that file. I am not getting. I am trying first time so

Comment: Are you sure it works in RN? Your example shows it in a React-DOM style.